# Interface Class

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I don't understand about using interface class clearly. I read a lot of article and tutorial about interface class related OOP so I know what is the interface but I do understand about using in real project.

For example,

I made IPayment interface class. and I defined 2 method that use common of all payment class.

```
public interface IPayment 
{
  void MakePayment(OrderInfo orderInfo);
  void MakeRefund (OrderInfo orderInfo);
}
```

I made 3 payment classes that are CreditCardPayment, PaypalPayment and GooglePayment.

and I defined 2 methods in each classes.

**I am confused in this part, I need to make OrderInfo class that contain order information that need to be used for processing payment or refund.
And each class need different information.**

CreditCartPayment class need Credit Card No, Expiration Date ....
But the other payment class are not.

And GooglePayment class need Google Order number but the other class are not.

So, finally the OrderInfo class has to have many extra field. And it look so dirty...

Ex)

```
Public class OrderInfo 
{
  /* For Common */
  string orderNo {get; set;}
  string customerNo { get; set;}
  decimal amount {get; set;}

  /* For Credit Card */
  string CCNum {get; set;}
  string expDate { get; set;}

  /* For Google */
  string googleOrderID {get; set;}
  ...

  /* For Paypal */
  ...
}
```

My question is,

In this case, is it right to use IPayment? or I need to define each class with right parameters without Interface class?

I guess the advantage of using Interface class is easy to figure out payment class in later. because the Interface class will show what methods are defined in each payment class. is there the other pros?

and do you have any advice for the understanding Interface class in real world?

**[EDIT]**

Thank you for all the advice.

I write the example codes again. could you please review this code?

```
public interface IPayment 
{
  void MakePayment(OrderInfo orderInfo); // !!
  void MakeRefund (OrderInfo orderInfo); // !!
}

public class OrderInfo 
{
  protected string OrderNo {get; set;}
  protected string CustomerNo { get; set;}
  protected decimal Amount {get; set;}
}

public class CreditCardPaymentInfo : OrderInfo
{
  string CCNum {get; set;}
  string ExpDate { get; set;}
}

public class GooglePaymentInfo : OrderInfo
{
  string GoogleOrderID {get; set;}
}

public class PaypalPaymentInfo : OrderInfo
{
  string PaypalID {get; set;}
}



public void MakePayment()
{
    IPayment paymentModule;
    // Get Order Info 
    if(orderType == "Paypal"){
        paymentModule = new PaypalPayment();

        PaypalPaymentInfo orderInfo = new PaypalPaymentInfo();
        orderInfo.PaypalID = "TEST";
    }else if(orderType == "Google"){
        paymentModule = new GooglePayment();

        GooglePaymentInfo orderInfo = new GooglePaymentInfo();
        orderInfo.GoogleOrderID = "TEST";
    }else{
        paymentModule = new CreditCardPayment();

        CreditCardPaymentInfo orderInfo = new CreditCardPaymentInfo();
        orderInfo.CCNum = "1111111111111111";
        orderInfo.ExpDate = "11/11";
    }

    orderInfo.OrderNo = "123";
    orderInfo.CustomerNo = "ABC";
    orderInfo.Amount = 12.20m;

    paymentModule.MakePayment();
}
```

It occur an error :

**Error 1   'com.WebUI.Models.CreditCardPaymentInfo' does not implement interface member 'com.WebUI.Models.IPaymentProcess.makeRefund(WebUI.Models.RefundModel)'**

I think I need to fix the Interface class. Anybody know how should I fix it please?

Comment: @JanDvorak: This is C#.  For reference, the `{get; set;}` is an easy way to tell C# and Java apart -- Java doesn't have properties at all, much less automatic ones.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I'm kinda torn on it.  This is really more an OOP question than a C# one.

Comment: @cHao - This isn't an OOP question, the author doesn't know C#, hence the question.  I mean the code doesn't even implement the interface, which I will be honest, there are many examples on how to do that.

Comment: @Ramhound The code shown isn't *meant* to implement the interface, it's the parameter to the interface's methods. The OP is asking how he can have different `IPayment` implementations that require different things from `OrderInfo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach is to make `OrderInfo` a base class and make your provider-specific payment types *subclasses* of it, like so:

```
public class OrderInfo 
{
  /* For Common - Protected members are accessible to subclasses! */
  protected string OrderNo {get; set;}
  protected string CustomerNo { get; set;}
  protected decimal Amount {get; set;}
}

public class CreditCardPaymentInfo : OrderInfo
{
  /* For Credit Card */
  string CCNum {get; set;}
  string ExpDate { get; set;}
}

public class GooglePaymentInfo : OrderInfo
{
  /* For Google */
  string GoogleOrderID {get; set;}
  ...
}

public class PaypalPaymentInfo : OrderInfo
{
  /* For Paypal */
  ...
}
```

You can then implement your Payment classes like so, and fulfil the requirements of the IPayment interface:

```
public class PaypalPayment : IPayment
{
    public void MakePayment(PaypalPaymentInfo orderInfo)
    {
      ...
    }

    public void MakeRefund (PaypalPaymentInfo orderInfo)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

Since `PaypalPaymentInfo` can be used wherever `OrderInfo` is specified, this is a valid implementation of an `IPayment`. You can follow the same pattern for your credit-card and Google payment implementations.

Comment: Why not make the base class abstract and implement IPayment there if you take this route?

Comment: Note we're talking about different components of the design: the base class `OrderInfo` and its subclasses, none of which *implement* `IPayment`, solve the OP's problem of an `OrderInfo` class that contains payment-type-specific members. It's the `IPayment` implementations that consume these payment-type-specific subclasses while fulfilling the `IPayment` contract.

Comment: @Dan J I wrote the codes again with your advice, could you review the codes again please? I put it into edited question.

Comment: @Dan J could you show me the Interface class too please?, I got an error : Error 1 'Ecom.WebUI.Models.CreditCardPaymentInfo' does not implement interface member 'Ecom.WebUI.Models.IPaymentProcess.makeRefund(WebUI.Models.RefundModel)'

Comment: @Expertwannabe - That error just means that you need a `makeRefund(RefundModel model)` function in your `CreditCardPaymentInfo` class.  I believe you can right-click on the interface where the error is and choose "Implement Interface" and it'll create all the methods for you.

Answer (score 5):

The right way to implement this would be to make a class for each type of payment, but use them as a general `IPayment`. So you'd have:

`public class CreditPayment : IPayment`

`public class GooglePayment : IPayment`

`public class PaypalPayment : IPayment`

Then to use a payment:

```
public class PaymentUser
{
   private IPayment _payment;

   public PaymentUser(//args)
   {
      //Which payment to be used would be based on args. Using a factory here is common
      _payment = new CreditPayment(//args);
   }
}
```

Now you have an `IPayment` that's been created for you, and you don't care what type it is other than knowing it fulfills your contract!

So somewhere down the line you can say

```
public void MakePayment(OrderInfo order)
{
   _payment.MakePayment(order);
}
```

And you don't even know which type of `IPayment` you used. This increases extensibility since you don't care what type is executing the method so long as it adheres to the `IPayment` interface.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain it with simple example.

Think of a simple method(just for example) saying `int rectanglePerimeter(int x, int y)`. This method simply take two numbers, multiplies them and returns the result. Now you can implement it in two ways:

first: using multiplication

```
    return x*y;
```

second: using addition

```
    int res = 0;
    for(int i=0; i< length; i++){
      res+= width;
    }
    return res;
```

Now if you want to keep the consumer code of this method independent of the implementation, you can simply define an `Interface` having the method signature as `int rectanglePerimeter(int x, int y)`. This may be implemented by different implementation bodies in different way but all will have to adhere to the method definition and your consumer code pattern will not change based on the implementaton.

Now let's take more practical example of `Database queries execution` using `Connection` interface. Since there are several Database providers, they all have different implementation(database drivers) to support the connection with database, but they all provide the same method support as defined in the `Connection` Interface e.g. `commit()`, `createStatement()`, `rollback()` & `close()`.

This makes usage independent of the implementation. As you can imagine now, **`Interface` plays a service contract role between consumers and service providers.** Its may be possible that both consumers and service providers are your own classes or it may be coming from two different groups/organizations.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you some example about how interface works. Anyways you have a lot of aspects to use   *interface*

**Interface inheritance** (aka type inheritance): This is also known as subtyping. Interfaces provide a mechanism for
specifying a relationship between otherwise unrelated classes, typically by specifying a set of common methods each
implementing class must contain. Interface inheritance promotes the design concept of program to interfaces not to
implementations. This also reduces the coupling or implementation dependencies between systems. In Java, you can
implement any number of interfaces. This is more flexible than implementation inheritance because it won’t lock you into
specific implementations which make subclasses difficult to maintain. So care should be taken not to break the
implementing classes by modifying the interfaces.

Example:

Lets say we have class named `Person`.

The `Person` contains fields like: age, first name, last name, ID, military ID (for military service for example), work place and so on. Now, you want to provide *Person* info to several institutions like work, army, facebook. Your work don't want to hear everything about your military Id or nick name in facebook. Therefore we create several interfaces: `MilitaryItf,`WorkItf`,`WebPersonItf`. In`WebPersonItf`you define methods`get/set`Nick name, First Name, gmail and so on. In`MilitaryItf`you provide`get/set` for age, health, military ID, start/end date of service .... At last each agency use only interested methods derived from 'Person'.

Answer (score 1):

A interface is used to be able to use classes that do not inherit from the same base. What you did for the three classes looks sound. But it is also possible to create a 'base class' that you can use for inheriting the functions in your interface.

Your problem with `OrderInfo` does not stem from the interface but more from the fact that you basicly need a different kind of object. More or less, your interface is not suitable for your `CreditCartPayment` class.

One way out is to create a class inheriting from the `OrderInfo` class, say `CredidCardOrderInfo` and use that with the `CreditCardPayment` class. You can use any instance of the `CreditCardOrderInfo` class as if it is a `OrderInfo` instance. Then you add a line

```
CreditCardOrderInfo info = orderInfo as CreditCardOrderInfo;
if (info == null) throw new ArgumentException("orderInfo has no credit card order info");
```

It keeps things together... but still is dirty.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of an interface is to allow an entity which holds a reference to an object that implements it to use that object without having to know which of potentially many possible implementations it might happen to be.  As such, an interface should generally only define methods which will be potentially useful for all of the classes that implement it.

Based on your scenario, it sound like what's needed is not an interface for the payment-processing class, but rather an interface `IOrderWithPayment`, for objects which are expected to encapsulate some form of order information and a payment processor object which can accept it (i.e. that particular kind of order information).  That interface would then have `MakePayment` and `MakeRefund` methods which feed the order information to the payment processor.  An object holding an `IOrderWithPayment` would not have to worry about which type of order information or payment processor was encapsulated within it, since every class that implements `IOrderWithPayment` would encapsulate order-info and payment-processor types that were compatible with each other.

Note that it would be possible to define a single generic class which could handle all compatible combinations of order-info and payment-processor objects, provided that those objects included suitable declarations about what they could accept, but that would require using some fairly advanced concepts.  For now, it's probably easier to define distinct types that encapsulate the compatible combinations of objects.